# Ubuntu install on brand new drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, disk-usage, drive

Brand new, never been touched drive.

Bootable USB being used to install Ubuntu 16.04.2. I can step through a few options, but once the install is supposed to start I get the error "This computer has 0 bytes left" or "No space left on this drive (or something like that).

This drive is brand spankin new, but I also had this exact issue on the last drive I tried it on (which is why I bought the new drive anyway).

Anyone have any ideas why the installer isn't running like I would expect?

Comment: **Update #1**
Installer apparently partitioned parts of the drive, but the installer still gives the "error: no space left on device" message

Comment: **Update #2**
Tried to use DBAN to wipe it all and start new, but the BIOS doesn't recognize it. (Asus F555UA). There is a "Force" option to force it to use the USB, and DBAN will load, but if it tries to execute it will hang and crash.

So still back to the drawing board.

Comment: **Update #3**
Screenshot of what I'm looking at during install

http://imgur.com/a/UzWBN

Comment: **Update #4**

Screenshot of how the installer is partitioning the drive. This was taken after the installer hung again (stuck on that screenshot from Update #3). I reboot, it now doesn't say Install Over Ubuntu..., just the regular Erase Disk and Install. I select "something else" and this is a look at the 1TB drive.

http://imgur.com/A3DdtXo

Comment: As the disk is partitioned already, you'd have to choose `Erase Disk and Install` - assuming there are no important data on the disk.

Comment: Have been selecting that, but having the same results.

Comment: Then try "something else" and select all partitions needed and mount points (swap should be used automatically). Select EFI, click change and select type EFI partition, do the same for `sda2`, choosing EXT4 with mount point "/". And please, pretty please, **whenever you need to add information, EDIT your question, do not use comments for that.**